# Como puedo poner comillas simples dentro de comillas simples, me bota error

Tags: javascript

amigos me bota error comillas simples dentro de comillas simples en javascript
[image: amigos me muestra error en comillas]

Comment: Prueba invirtiendo tus comillas simples a comillas dobles y viceversa.

Comment: solo pon comillas doble `" "`

Comment: Muchos no podemos ver las imágenes porque estamos detrás de proxies, esa es una entre muchas otras razones por las que las imágenes de código no son recomendables.

Comment: Al hacer una pregunta en este sitio se debería poner el código como texto en lugar de ponerlo como imagen.

Answer (score 2):

**Para poner comillas simples puedes hacerlo de estas dos formas:**

```
var comillas = 'ejemplo con \' comilla simple';

var comillas = "ejemplo con ' comilla simple";
```

El resultado es el mismo:

> ejemplo con ' comilla simple

Comment: si me soluciono amigo el slash volteado, pero me he dado cuenta si no pongo la etiqueta </script> todo bien, pero si la pongo bota error

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras:

```
var comillas = "un 'ejemplo' cualquiera";
var comillas = 'un \'ejemplo\' cualquiera';
var comillas = `un 'ejemplo' cualquiera`; //Sólo EcmaScript6
```